# Stop TabBar Animating During Transitioning Between Child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I am transitioning Child ViewControllers, from a ViewController to a TabBarController.

I am using this method to do so;

```
 private func transitionController(to new: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        current.willMove(toParent: nil)
        addChild(new)
        transition(from: current, to: new, duration: 6, options: [], animations: {
        }) { completed in
            self.current.removeFromParent()
            new.didMove(toParent: self)
            self.current = new
            completion?()
        }
    }
```

However, when presenting the TabBarController it animates the TabBar up from outside the window.

How do I stop this? - I Just want a simple cross-dissolve animation such as presenting a controller modally.

### Current Animation

[image: tabbar animation]

Comment: did you try to give `0` instead of `6` to `duration`?

Comment: @emrcftci I changed the animation duration to 6 so that I could illustrate the tab bar animating clearer.

Comment: Have you tried using `options: .transitionCrossDissolve` instead of `options: []`?

Comment: This doesn't change anything to the Tab Bar, unfortunately.  I have done further research and I have seen the effect I need but it is with Container Views not Child View Controllers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818544/cannot-switch-to-another-child-view-controller-in-container-view

Comment: @DavidLintin - if you are adding your Tab Bar Controller as a child view controller, you are not really *transitioning from `UIViewController` to `UITabarController`* ... you're ***adding*** it. Can you create a [mre]? I haven't even benn able to come up with anything that reproduces the "tab bar animation" that you've shown.